# LiveCharts legend color doesn´t match series color, how can i fix it?

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I am working with the opensource library [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net/) in a wpf usercontrol.

All of my visualizations are working as intended except for my boxplots. For some reason the color of the legend on my boxplots doesn´t match the actual series. 
In bare bones test app it looks like this.
[image]

Here is how i set up the chart and populate it.

```
public MainWindow()
{            
    chart1 = new Chart();
    var testValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<double>>>();
    testValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, List<double>>("test", new List<double>() { 40, 30, 20, 10, 500 }));
    testValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, List<double>>("tust", new List<double>() { 80, 10, 90, 30, 50 }));
    chart1.AddBoxplotSeries(testValues, "titel");
}

public void AddBoxplotSeries(List<KeyValuePair<string, List<double>>> data, string title)
{
    CartesianVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ChartValues<OhlcPoint> values = new ChartValues<OhlcPoint>();
    string[] labels = new string[data.Count];
    //ChartValues<OhlcPoint> values = new ChartValues<OhlcPoint>();
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        double[] ohlc = new double[4];
        ohlc[0] = item.Value.LowerQuartile();
        ohlc[1] = item.Value.Maximum();
        ohlc[2] = item.Value.Minimum();
        ohlc[3] = item.Value.UpperQuartile();

        labels[data.IndexOf(item)] = data[data.IndexOf(item)].Key;

        values.Add(new OhlcPoint( ohlc[0], ohlc[1], ohlc[2], ohlc[3] ));
    }

    CartesianSeries.Add(new CandleSeries()
    {
        Values = values,
        Title = title
    });

    XAxisLabels = labels;

    LabelFormatter = value => value.ToString("N");
}
```

Am i doing something wrong or is this a bug ?